# piping to .csv random works in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, pipe

I'm running a script that shows pending Windows updates.
The script has been set to show the information on screen via `-verbose`, and `pipe` the results to a .csv file.
The script runs fine and will create the .csv file. However, every now and again the file will not be filled up with any data.

**Note:** There is data to put into the file because -verbose will display the pending updates on the screen, they're just not being piped into the file.
Here is the script i'm using:

```
$list = Get-Data C:\Users\accountname\Desktop\machinelist.txt
Get-WUList -Computername $list -Verbose | ConvertTo-csv C:\Users\accountname\Desktop\file.csv
```

Comment: what happens if you leave off the `-Verbose` parameter?

Comment: it'll still run. the updates will show in a small progress bar. verbose just show the data on screen as well. it'll show the number of pending updates.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27244731) your question and insert the code for your `Get-Data` function?

Comment: You probably need to use `Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\accountname\Desktop\file.csv' -NoTypeInformation` instead of `ConvertTo-csv` which is not meant for writing to file.

Comment: @keiko909 - i was wondering if perhaps there was some odd interaction with the verbose output. glad to know that is not the case. thanks! [*grin*] ///// i missed the use of `ConvertTo-Csv` ... theo is correct that you likely otta not use that ... instead, use `Export-Csv` to do things "correctly".

Comment: @Theo Gave that a try. still doesn't work. I get the .csv file, but it is empty. There is data to put in it as i can see the pending updates. Not sure where i'm going wrong.

Comment: So what does `Get-WUList` return? Please show us the code

Comment: @Theo Get-WUList is a module that retrieves all the pending updates for a machine. I'm unable to post the coding, however the script works fine, it is the piping function that I am having the issues with

Comment: @Theo the script is here: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/1.6.1.1/Content/Get-WUList.ps1